# How do I enable LinkTimeOptimization with Clion?

Tags: cmake, clion, lto

I'd like to have my program link time optimized. Where do I have to enter it to enable it?

If it matters (I hope it doesn't): I'm using MinGW-w64 5.0 on Windows.

edit: I really don't see why it wouldn't matter that I'm using CLion. I'm aware that - for now - it uses CMake as underlying build system.

But a) In the future CMake won't be the only build system that CLion will support ([See here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2014/09/clion-answers-frequently-asked-questions/)), so refering to CMake wouldn't solve the problem itself.

And b) adjusting the CMakeLists.txt would still require, that I configure each project individually. I asked for a way to configure the IDE, so it would do it for me.

I also don't this that it's an unsolvable problem per se. There could be a configuration or a PlugIn that does the trick. I failed to find it.. yet that doesn't mean that my question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 3):

In general, this has nothing to do with *CLion*, but is a matter of CMake.

The problem, however, is that the appropriate flags differ among the compilers and linkers.

As you are using MinGW and, as far as I know that implies GCC, you can try the following as a rough starting point:

```
if(${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} MATCHES GNU)
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE} -flto")
    set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE} -flto")
    set(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE} -flto")
endif()
```

However, I'd recommend using target properties (assuming you have a target `MyTarget` as an executable or shared library defined):

```
if(${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} MATCHES GNU)
  set_property(TARGET MyTarget
               APPEND PROPERTY LINK_FLAGS -lto)
endif()
```

Comment: This works as a CMake solution. Unfortunately CMake isn't the only build system that CLion will support in the future. So breaking it down to CMake doesn't fully solve the problem.